# Kendo Grid missing text after space when using custom DropdownEditor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a `Kendo UI Grid` which has a `DropDown` used to edit the `row`. I want to add the value of two `columns` from the `DropDown` to the `grid data-source`. My example works almost perfectly except that only the first characters in the `DropDown field` up to the first space get added, anything after that gets truncated. So the `DropDown field "PartNumber"` with a  `value="P 2929"` ends up being added as just `"P"`.

I have a [JS Bin example here](http://jsbin.com/sujom/15/edit) that recreates my problem.

Comment: I just realized that if I tab into the field I can see all the text. this may be a template issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template for your part number column in your grid you need quotes for the value attribute of the input element. The html isn't valid anymore if there's a space in the value

> value=P 1234

instead of

> value="P 1234"

You should quote all of them in all of your column templates but it will work when there aren't any spaces in the data value.

You have:

value= #:data.PartNumber || \'\'#

Change it to:

value="#:data.PartNumber || \'\'#"

I tested this in JS Bin and it works like you wanted after the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the strip code in your code below:

```
value="#:data.PartNumber || \'\'#"
```

by

```
value="#:(data.PartNumber != undefined ? data.PartNumber : \'\')  #"
```

I already tested and it works!

Comment: I wish you can try my approuch too, because let the value without quotes could not work in all browsers. I guess I am doing this in a better way.

Comment: I did try it and could not make it work. Can you edit the JS Bin and make it work>

Comment: Maybe you are right man... I am not sure how many other users change the code at the same time I am coding it, if it doesn’t work I guess It really not work. Sorry about that. I didn't wish try to make that thing work any more... is much slow to test.